# Enable clustering with event_name column for data streamed into Big Query from Firebase Analytics

Tags: google-bigquery

How to enable clustering around event_name column for data that is streamed by Firebase Analytics into BigQuery?

Since most of our queries have event_name as a filter, our query performance and cost can improve: "[Clustering can improve the performance of certain types of queries such as queries that use filter clauses](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables)".

Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to re-materialize these tables, so you can get one non-nested, non-repeated column with the `event_name`.

So make sure to do something like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `dataset.new_table`
PARTITION BY DATE(timestamp)
CLUSTER BY event_name
AS

SELECT *, event_name, timestamp
# transform existing table to have event_name as a single column
```

How much data do you have by day? That's relevant too.

Comment: >How much data do you have by day?
4-6 GB

The dataset was automatically created when Firebase was linked to BigQuery and has the following structure: https://ibb.co/Tqb02Fx

After re-materializing, will the clustering be maintained for subsequent data streams/loads done by Firebase ?

Thanks

Comment: That's a good amount to cluster per day. You'll need to set up a pipeline to move data from a to b.